# PDO get last CRUD statement used

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, crud

I am implementing a log for CRUD queries, I only need to log create, update & delete queries.

Is there a PDO method to retrieve the last statement used? It should return something like `select`, `insert`?

I know about `lastInsertId` is there a similar method for which statement was used?

The problem lies in that the CRUD class my client use contains a method named execute which is basically used by everything, in the end, the problem is that this method can also be called directly from the code with custom SQL

So if I could just retrieve the last statement used that would be awesome because then I can catch this type of direct `SELECT` queries, would also make my code more DRY friendly since right now I set the statement used in, etc the `CRUD::create()`, `CRUD::update()` methods.

I could do some check on the query string being executed, but it's not really what I want to do

Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't even the 1st letter of the SQL enough to know what sort of statement it is?

Comment: No, there is no functionality like this. So just add it to that execute() method manually

Comment: Yes it is, but as I said I'd much rather want something build in than using my own check